# The space of communicative operator

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Assume $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{F}$,and $\dim V = n$. $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are linear transforms. and there exist a vector $\xi$, such that $V = <\xi, \sigma(\xi),\cdots,\sigma^{n-1}(\xi)>$, If $\sigma\tau =\tau\sigma$, show that ,there exist a polynomial $f(x)$, such that $f(\sigma)=\tau$.

---

I think if $\{\tau | \sigma\tau = \tau\sigma\}$ is spanned by $\Bbb{I}, \sigma,\cdots,\sigma^{n-1}$, the problem will work out. But I can't work out this problem through this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dimension of $V$ is exactly $n$, you have that $\xi, \sigma( \xi), \dots, \sigma^{n-1}(\xi)$ is a basis of $V$ (it is a set of $n$ elements spanning $V$).
Now write
$$\tau (\xi) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \lambda_{i} \sigma^i(\xi)$$
for some $\lambda_0, \dots, \lambda_{n-1} \in \mathbb{F}$.

Now, for all $v = a_0 \xi + a_1 \sigma(\xi)+ \dots + a_{n-1} \sigma^{n-1}(\xi) \in V$ (with $a_j \in \mathbb{F}$) you have

$$\tau (v) = \tau \left( \sum_j a_j \sigma^j(\xi) \right) = \sum_j a_j \tau\sigma^j(\xi) =
\sum_j a_j \sigma^j \tau (\xi)  = \sum_ja_j \sigma^j \left( \sum_i \lambda_{i} \sigma^i(\xi) \right) =$$

$$ = \sum_i \lambda_i \sigma^i \left( \sum_j a_j \sigma^j (\xi) \right) = \sum_i \lambda_{i} \sigma^i(v)$$

Hence $\tau = \sum_i \lambda_i \sigma^i$